# C# Use buttons to show stored procedure in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, procedure

I'm trying to create a WinForms, where when a user clicks a button it executes a stored procedure and then shows it in the listview. This is what I have come to atm.
I still need to figure out how to output the data into the listview.

This code is just a sample from my current program. I have taken the listview programming from MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace Bolche2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string connetionString;
                SqlConnection cnn;
                connetionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Bolche;Integrated Security=True";
                cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
                cnn.Open();
                SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("dbo.EVERYTHING_TASK1");
                _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cnn.Close();
            }
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  //CreateMyListView()
    {
            // Create a new ListView control.
            ListView listView1 = new ListView();
            listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), new Size(300, 200));

            // Set the view to show details.
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            // Allow the user to edit item text.
            listView1.LabelEdit = false;
            // Allow the user to rearrange columns.
            listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            // Display check boxes.
            listView1.CheckBoxes = false;
            // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            // Display grid lines.
            listView1.GridLines = true;

            // Create two ImageList objects.
            ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
            ImageList imageListLarge = new ImageList();

            // Initialize the ImageList objects with bitmaps.
            imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MySmallImage1.bmp"));
            imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MySmallImage2.bmp"));
            imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage1.bmp"));
            imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage2.bmp"));

            //Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge;
            listView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;

            // Add the ListView to the control collection.
            this.Controls.Add(listView1);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a listview inside of a listview index change?

Comment: I checked out the link and you should move the code from index change to another function like "createListView()" this would be your own function that could be called on load of program.

Comment: This is actually my first week using C#. What do you mean by it?

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { createListView();
            }

Comment: However, all that information can be set with the designer if you are using Visual Studio. When you want to add something to the listview then listview1.Items.Add();

Comment: @HaxCookiesDK To retrieve data from you database you should use a `DataReader`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader